# Understand do statement as parameter

Tags: haskell

I have following code snippet:

```
  main = scotty 3000 $ do
    get "/:word" $ do
      beam <- param "word"
      putStrLn "hello"
      html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"]
```

I do understand, how `do` statement works, it is just a syntax sugar for `>>=`, but the example above, how can it be, that I can pass `do` block as function parameter?

Comment: Higher order functions take functions as function parameters

Comment: Could you better define what's confusing you? You can pass eg. `(bar 7 + 3)` as an argument to an apropriately typed function `foo`. *Why* couldn't you pass `(x >>= baz z)` as the argument to another appropriately typed function?

Comment: `do` is not syntactical sugar for `>>=` itself.

Comment: I do not understand the code, that I post it above.

Comment: The type signature of `get` is `RoutePattern -> ActionM () -> ScottyM ()`, why can I pass a `do` block instead of  `ActionM ()` type?

Comment: @zero_coding It's not instead of. The `do` block has the type `ActionM ()`.

Comment: Could someone give me a simple example?

Comment: You say you understand it, but you clearly do not. You only understand that `do` syntax is syntactic sugar for *something*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define

```
twice :: IO () -> IO ()
twice a = do
   a
   a
```

...or in short `twice a = a>>a`.

You can certainly use this like

```
Prelude> twice (putStrLn "hello")
hello
hello
```

...but Haskellers prefer to save parens and write `twice $ putStrLn "hello"`.

You can also use it like

```
Prelude> twice $ putStrLn "hello" >> putStrLn "world"
hello
world
hello
world
```

Now, that monadic sequence can be converted to a do block:

```
Prelude> twice $ do{putStrLn "hello"; putStrLn "world"}
```

and with layout instead of braces&semicolons, this looks thus:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| twice $ do
Prelude|    putStrLn "hello"
Prelude|    putStrLn "world"
Prelude| :}
hello
world
hello
world
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/10/how-to-desugar-haskell-code.html provides several examples to show how various `do` expressions are desugared.

The single expression

```
do
  beam <- param "word"
  putStrLn "hello"
  html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"]
```

is first recursively desugared into multiple nested expressions:

```
do
  beam <- param "word"
  do putStrLn "hello"
     html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"]
```

The inner one desugars using the `>>` operator:

```
do
  beam <- param "word"
  (putStrLn "hello" >> html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"])
```

The resulting expression desugars using `>>=`:

```
param "word" >>= (\beam -> (putStrLn "hello" >> html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"])
```

*This* expression is what is seen as the argument to `get "/:word"`:

```
main = scotty 3000 $ do
  get "/:word" $ param "word" >>= (\beam -> (putStrLn "hello" >> html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"])
```

The last remaining `do` expression trivially desugars to

```
main = scotty 3000 $ get "/:word" $ param "word" >>= (\beam -> (putStrLn "hello" >> html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"])
```

as a single line `do` expression is just the wrapped expression itself (`do x = x`).